# XML Structure From SQL Query

Tags: sql, xml

I've been asked to provide some SQL data in XML format, which I have no previous experience with. After looking through some tutorials and playing around, I have the following, which isn't giving me what I need...

```
 DECLARE @Consignment_id decimal(18, 0) = '246002'

    SELECT      
        'OUT' AS Direction,
        (CONVERT(varchar(8), Consignment_id) + 
         UPPER(CONVERT(varchar(3), (SELECT DepotLocation FROM General 
                                    WHERE Uber = DeliveryPoint)))) AS ExternalReference,
        ('New') AS MessageType,
        (SELECT DepotLocation FROM General 
         WHERE Uber = CollectionPoint) AS storageLocationReference,
        ('1.0') AS Version,
        (SELECT 
             'HolyHead'AS pointOfExit,
             'Dublin' AS pointOfEntry,
             (SELECT 
                  'ROVRN' AS Code,
                  ('VehicleRegPlaceHolder') AS Text
              FROM      
                  Consignments
              WHERE     
                  Consignment_id = @Consignment_id
              FOR XML PATH('additionalInformation'), TYPE)
             'additionalInformations',
             (SELECT        
                  ('DeclarantPlaceHolder') AS Code
              FOR XML PATH('declarant'), TYPE),
             (SELECT ('DeclarantPlaceHolder') AS Code
              FOR XML PATH('consignee'), TYPE),
             (SELECT    (SELECT ('GB') AS Country,
                                ('IdentificationPlaceHolder')AS indentification,
                                ('6')AS mode,
                                ('IsAccompainedPlaceHolder')AS isAccompanied
                    FROM        Consignments
                    WHERE       Consignment_id=@Consignment_id
                    FOR XML PATH('borderTransportMeans'), TYPE),

                    (SELECT     ('DeclarantPlaceHolder')AS Code
                    FOR XML PATH('departureTransportMeans'), TYPE)
                        
                    FOR XML PATH('consignment'), TYPE)
                    'goodsShipment'
            FROM
            Consignments
            WHERE Consignment_id=@Consignment_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            'singleAdministrativeDocument'
FROM        Consignments
WHERE       Consignment_id=@Consignment_id
FOR XML PATH ('customsShipment'), ELEMENTS
```

This gives me the output on the image below. However, I need the "consignee" node within the "goodsShipment" node and above the "consignment" node. I've made several adjustments but haven't been able to accomplish this. Any ideas where I am going wrong? Thanks.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onGem.jpg)

Edit: Node names appear to have been supressed as I originally put them within brackets

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: please connect with me on LinkedIn